# How can I provide star rating metadata to search engines?

Tags: seo, meta-tags

Some search engines (including Google and Bing) display a star rating for things like movies and downloads on sites such as IMDB and cnet.

[image: screenshot]

How can I configure my site to provide this data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a Review [Microformat](http://blog.mozilla.com/faaborg/2006/12/11/microformats-part-0-introduction/). Google has [good documentation](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=146645) of what they use, but the full standard for the [hReview Microformat](http://microformats.org/wiki/hreview) should also be looked at, as it offers more properties.

Google lists

```
itemreviewed
rating
reviewer
dtreviewed
description
summary
```

Google also gives examples of [Individual reviews](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=146645#Individual_reviews) and [Aggregated reviews](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=146645#Aggregate_reviews).

Answer (score 0):

It's [microformats](http://microformats.org/) ([Google](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/05/introducing-rich-snippets.html))

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Schema Data](http://schema.org/Review), [Google Reviews](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/reviews?visit_id=1-636377048135364410-2381129023&rd=1) for Item reviewed, rating, reviewer, date, summary & etc.

Schema is allow from different Search Engine because they follow it for Rich Data showing at SERPs.